# The method split(String) is undefined for the type Scanner

Tags: java

Why is it that I cant use split method on `input`? In Eclipse it says: The method split(String) is undefined for the type Scanner. I dont know what I am doing wrong, if anyone could guide me in the right direction.

```
btnFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("C:\\");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                " Only .txt", "txt");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

        int code = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (code == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            Scanner input;
            try {
                input = new Scanner(selectedFile); // <-- Here
                String[] splits = input.next().split(" "); <-- And here

                for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
                    textArea.setText(splits[i]);
                    System.out.println(splits[i]);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to get a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) out of the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) before trying to [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) it. You're probably looking for [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) or [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29).

If you're trying to read a whole file in, you'll need to use a loop to read a line at a time until [`Scanner.hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) returns false. Alternately, you could just read the whole file into a `String` using [commons-io FileUtils.readFileToString()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29).

Comment: I am not sure what u mean. But I have tried String[] splits = input.nextLine().split(" "); but then I only get 1 word on console...

Comment: That means the line you read had only one word in it. In order to get more, you'd need to continue calling `nextLine()` to get more lines.

Comment: So I guess the question is how do I get them all out?

Comment: Actually thats what I thought I did with my FOR loop. As I understand it, Split chops every word in to a Array. So I am iterating through the array, but it only displays the first word.

Comment: I have edited above code to String[] splits = input.next().split(" ");

Comment: Read the docs on Scanner linked in my answer and maybe visit the [Scanner tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html). If all you want is to read each word from a file, then you don't need the `split()` at all. The `next()` method returns the next word, so just call that until you run out of words.